# Is it possible to use libsvm in cuda?

Tags: machine-learning, cuda, svm, gpgpu, libsvm

I wonder If I can use libsvm in cuda.

I look for best parameters by cross validation, so I have to run same code around 4000 with different parameters.

I wonder If I can run the cross validation in parallel with cuda,

instead of using:

```
for i in range(4000):
    predict(parameter)
find_best_parameter()
```

Comment: I wouldn't expect so. Cuda is a platform for quickly performing homogeneous computation, e.g. when you multiply matrices there are a lot of similar operations. when you do a parameter search, it isn't the case.

Answer (score 1):

In the official webpage of the libsvm software you can find this sentence:

Python, R, MATLAB, Perl, Ruby, Weka, Common LISP, CLISP, Haskell, OCaml, LabVIEW, and PHP interfaces. C# .NET code and CUDA extension is available.

And there is a link to a GPU implementation:

http://mklab.iti.gr/project/GPU-LIBSVM

Comment: Note it only supports classification with RBF kernel, nothing else.

Comment: I checked GPU-LIBSVM, and as Katz mentioned, they only support classification w/ RBF. I want to use regression

Comment: I see, libsvm is mainly used in classification problems for regression problem there are other kernel algorithms like Gaussian Processes that have shown better accuracy. Probably, for that reason nobody has implemented a GPU svm for regression. I have seen in the past other GPU libraries for libsvm but non of them implemented the formulation for regression problems (https://github.com/ksopyla/KMLib).